# configurar virtual host no apache2

Tags: apache, linux

Estou com dificuldade em configurar meu virtual host no Apache2 com Debian.

Eu criei a pasta:

```
mkdir /var/www/site/public_html
```

dentro desse diretório criei um arquivo `index.html`.

Depois disso configurei o virtual host assim:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerName site.org
 ServerAlias www.site.org
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site/public_html/
</VirtualHost>
```

Ai se vou acessar através da url http://192.168.0.100/site, ele não acessa a página, somente se acesso por http://192.168.0.100/site/public_html.

Onde estou errando, pois me perdi toda nisso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O VirtualHost vale quando você acessa com o nome especificado (no caso, site.org), porque ele existe para servir vários sites usando um único servidor. O acesso via IP vai pegar o site default, que não é site.org. Acho que se comentar fora o ServerName/ServerAlias, ou criar uma segunda configuração VirtualHost sem esses itens, ele vai pegar como default.

Answer (score 1):

Nas configurações do apache (httpd.conf), procure a diretiva `NameVirtualHost`. Caso exista, desative-a.

Na tag VirtualHost, defina o ip do servidor:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
```

O IP 127.0.0.1 é ilustrativo. Troque-o pelo IP do servidor.

Esteja ciente de que há algumas diferenças entre Apache 2.2 e 2.4 que podem afetar o funcionamento.

Consulte a documentação: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html